# Delphi parsing a Json with multiple array types?

Tags: json, delphi

Following is my JSON:

```json
{
  "forms": {
    "frmLogin": [
      {
        "frmLoginPg": "Se connecter - Application de gestion de PC"
      },
      {
        "lbl_login_Title": "Application de gestion Pc"
      },
      {
        "lbl_loginName": "Nom d'utilisateur"
      },
      {
        "lblLanguage": "langue préférée"
      },
      {
        "btnLogin": "Se connecter"
      },
      {
        "btnReset_Loginfrm": "Réinitialiser"
      }
    ],
    "frmHome": [
      {
        "frmHomepg": "Accueil"
      },
      {
        "lbladdUser_Title": "Ajouter un utilisateur"
      },
      {
        "lblName": "prénom"
      },
      {
        "lblEmail": "EMail"
      },
      {
        "popmemFile": "Fichier"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am trying to get the values assigned to each key so I can change the `Caption` of each component.

I tried the following way, but I am getting an `Invalid class typecast` error:

```pascal
function Translationspg.GetTranslationsJson(formNameJson, frmName_FORMJson
  : TComponentName; formsam: TForm): string;
var
  lJsonBytes: TBytes;
  lJsonVal, lJsonScenar: TJSONValue;
  lJsonScenarioValue: string; // lJsonString,
  lJsonObj: TJSONObject; // , lJsonScenario
  lJsonArray: TJSONArray;
  lJsonScenarioEntry: TJSOnString;
  lJsonPair: TJSONPair;
begin
  lJsonBytes := TFile.ReadAllBytes(scJSONFileName_French);
  lJsonScenar := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(lJsonBytes, 0);
  if lJsonScenar <> nil then
  begin
    lJsonArray := lJsonScenar as TJSONArray;

    for lJsonVal in lJsonArray do
    begin
      lJsonObj := lJsonVal as TJSONObject;
      lJsonPair := lJsonObj.Get(formNameJson);
      lJsonScenarioEntry := lJsonPair.JsonString;
      lJsonScenarioValue := lJsonScenarioEntry.Value;        
    end;
  end;
  Result := lJsonScenarioValue;
end;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
lJsonArray := lJsonScenar as TJSONArray
```

The root of your JSON is not an array. It is an object. That objects has a single name/value pair, named `forms`. You need to read that, and then look for the form by name. Like this:

```
lJsonObj := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(lJsonBytes, 0) as TJSONObject;
lJsonObj := lJsonObj.GetValue('forms') as TJSONObject;
lJsonPair := lJsonObj.Get(formNameJson);
....
```

This program

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.JSON, System.IOUtils;

procedure Main(const fileName, formName: string);
var
  lJsonBytes: TBytes;
  lJsonObj: TJSONObject;
  lJsonArray: TJSONArray;
  lJsonValue: TJSONValue;
  lJsonPair: TJSONPair;
begin
  lJsonBytes := TFile.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
  lJsonObj := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(lJsonBytes, 0) as TJSONObject;
  lJsonObj := lJsonObj.GetValue('forms') as TJSONObject;
  lJsonArray := lJsonObj.GetValue(formName) as TJSONArray;
  Writeln(fileName, ' ', formName);
  for lJsonValue in lJsonArray do begin
    lJsonObj := lJsonValue as TJSONObject;
    for lJsonPair in lJsonObj do begin
      Writeln(lJsonPair.JsonString.ToString, ': ', lJsonPair.JsonValue.ToString);
    end;
  end;
  Writeln;
end;

begin
  try
    Main('C:\desktop\json.txt', 'frmLogin');
    Main('C:\desktop\json.txt', 'frmHome');
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

has this output:

```
C:\desktop\json.txt frmLogin
"frmLoginPg": "Se connecter - Application de gestion de PC"
"lbl_login_Title": "Application de gestion Pc"
"lbl_loginName": "Nom d'utilisateur"
"lblLanguage": "langue préférée"
"btnLogin": "Se connecter"
"btnReset_Loginfrm": "Réinitialiser"

C:\desktop\json.txt frmHome
"frmHomepg": "Accueil"
"lbladdUser_Title": "Ajouter un utilisateur"
"lblName": "prénom"
"lblEmail": "EMail"
"popmemFile": "Fichier"
```