# How to parse this type of JSON data in Delphi?

Tags: json, parsing, delphi

How do I parse the following Json in Delphi?

This is my first post, and I've taken care to search as much as I can before asking this question,
so please kindly let me know if I posted wrongly in any way.

I would like to get the value of "name_of_centre" in the "records" array

Thank you for any kind assistance.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i : integer;
  jsonRoot: TJSONValue;
  jsonObj: TJSONObject;
  jsonArr: TJSONArray;
begin
  jsonRoot := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(memo2.Lines.text);
  try
    jsonObj := jsonRoot as TJSONObject;
    jsonObj := jsonObj.GetValue('result') as TJSONObject;
    jsonArr := jsonObj.GetValue('records') as TJSONArray;
    showmessage( jsonArr.Count.ToString );  // works ok

    for i := 0 to jsonArr.Count - 1 do
    begin
      jsonObj := jsonArr.Items[i] as TJSONObject;
      showmessage( jsonObj.GetValue('name_of_centre').Value );   // error here
    end;
  finally
    jsonRoot.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I've checked out
[Delphi parsing a Json with multiple array types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40908595/delphi-parsing-a-json-with-multiple-array-types)

[How to parse this json data in Delphi 10 Seattle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61210350/how-to-parse-this-json-data-in-delphi-10-seattle)
 (especially this one)

and a few other links... but the JSON format seems different.

Any advice?

```
{
    "help": "testing",
    "success": true,
    "result": {
        "resource_id": "data_resource",
        "fields": [
            {
                "type": "int4",
                "id": "_id"
            },
            {
                "type": "text",
                "id": "name_of_centre"
            },
            {
                "type": "text",
                "id": "location_of_centre"
            },
            {
                "type": "text",
                "id": "type_of_centre"
            },
            {
                "type": "text",
                "id": "owner"
            },
            {
                "type": "numeric",
                "id": "no_of_outlets"
            },
            {
                "type": "numeric",
                "id": "no_of_branches"
            }
        ],
        "records": [
            {
                "location_of_centre": "Kings Road",
                "no_of_outlets": "12",
                "no_of_branches": "0",
                "name_of_centre": "Kings Road Centre",
                "type_of_centre": "HC",
                "owner": "Private",
                "_id": 1
            },
            {
                "location_of_centre": "Queens",
                "no_of_outlets": "14",
                "no_of_branches": "1",
                "name_of_centre": "Queens Centre",
                "type_of_centre": "HC",
                "owner": "Public",
                "_id": 2
            }
        ],
        "_links": {
            "start": "ignore",
            "next": "ignore2"
        },
        "limit": 2,
        "total": 10
    }
}
```

Comment: "error here" Would be nice to know *what* error you're geting.

Comment: Have you tried [`GetValue`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.JSON.TJSONValue.GetValue) / [`TryGetValue`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.JSON.TJSONValue.TryGetValue)? It accepts a path to the value. `jsonRoot.GetValue<string>('result.records[0].name_of_centre')`. But this will get you only single value though.

Comment: You need to cast to `TJSONString` before you can access the `Value` property.

Comment: @Olivier no, you don't. `Value()` is a virtual method in the `TJSONAncestor` base class, and `jsonObj.GetValue()` returns a `TJSONValue` that derives from `TJSONAncestor`.

Comment: @PeterWolf I see nothing wrong with this JSON or your code, so it should not be crashing.  You are just going to have to debug it to find out what is really happening.  Chances are, `jsonObj.GetValue('name_of_centre')` is returning a `nil` pointer when it shouldn't be.

Comment: I have compiled your example using Delphi 10.4 Sidney and it works perfectly. Maybe you are using an outdated Delphi version?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the many replies.

Olivier : I've included the error in this amended code.

Peter : I tried using
jsonRoot.GetValue('result.records[0].name_of_centre')
and it does give me the value of name_of_centre.  Good start.
But I'm hoping to get this code to give me the number of items in Array and I iterate the array, instead of hard-code. Thanks.

Remy : strangely though, it works today.  It doesn't get Invalid Typecast
at showmessage( jsonObj.GetValue('name_of_centre').Value );

fpiette : I use Delphi 10.3 RIO.

Thanks to everyone for replying.

Is there a need to use jsonRoot.Free;  -- i saw this in a posting on stackoverflow.com... How about jsonObj.Free?

```
jsonRoot := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(memo2.Lines.text);
try
  jsonObj := jsonRoot as TJSONObject;
  jsonObj := jsonObj.GetValue('result') as TJSONObject;
  showmessage( jsonObj.ToString );

  jsonArr := jsonObj.GetValue('records') as TJSONArray;

  showmessage( jsonArr.Count.ToString );

  for i := 0 to jsonArr.Count - 1 do
  begin
    jsonObj := jsonArr.Items[i] as TJSONObject;
    if jsonObj .GetValue('name_of_centre').Value = null then
      showmessage('null');
```

// previously had an Invalid Typecast
        showmessage( jsonObj.GetValue('name_of_centre').Value );
      end;
    finally
      jsonRoot.Free;
    end;

Comment: "*Is there a need to use jsonRoot.Free*" - yes. You need to free the `TJSONValue` that `ParseJSONValue()` returns when you are done using it. "*How about jsonObj.Free?*" - no, because it is owned by `jsonRoot` and will be freed automatically when `jsonRoot` is freed

Comment: Remy, noted with thanks!  Much appreciated for all the kind help from everyone.